# Bug in top users per tag (?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-users

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/topusers
2. Go to top answerers
3. Mouse over number of answers provided (i.e. number just left from the picture)
4. **Mouseover hint says "143 questions asked" (Should be something like "143 answers provided")**
5. Now, go to top askers and do the same
6. It says "x questions asked" - here it's ok.

Tested on Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in latest, will be deployed with the next deploy.

Thanks for reporting this